# array initialization zero versus assigned zero

Tags: java

I have a simple question I don't seem to find answer of. I think it is really simple and I can take it as language quirks.

```
 int[] newArray=new int[5];
```

will initialize an array and have all zeros in all 5 positions.

```
newArray[4]=0; 
//versus not assigning any value to specific position newArray[4]
```

Are two same thing? If not, how to differentiate between those two?

How can I differentiate between zeros that were placed automatically when the array was created versus zeros that was assigned in the program at some point?

The main reason I am asking this is I have a program that assigns some integer value at random position in array which can also be 0. While searching, I want to know which zeros were assigned by program versus which were the initialized zero.

Comment: The result is the same. All 0 are created equal.

Comment: Apart from that pesky negative 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you put `int`s in your array they are equivalent because the default value of `int` is **0**. You won't be able to differentiate the two because **0** equals **0**.

If you use `Integer` however the array will be initialized with `null`s. In that case you can tell whether a value was set or not.

If you want to be able to tell the difference you can use references.

Answer (score 1):

`int[] newArray=new int[5]` will initialize all elements to 0 by default.

`newArray[4]=0` will set the value of 5th element to 0. All other's will be by default anyways. So there's no difference between the two.

To understand this set `newArray[4]=10` instead.

Now the array content is `{0,0,0,0,10}`

Answer (score 1):

Why do you say quirk?  It's clear that every reference and primitive has an initial default value in Java.  For int it's `0`.  For references it's `null`.

Answer (score 0):

If you instance a variable as member of a class, it will have a default value: 0 for numbers and null for Objects. But if you declare that variable inside a method, compiler don't assign a default value for this variable, so its contents is undeffinded until you set it.

So if you do it inside a method, is not equivalent ;-)

Comment: So,int[] newArray=new int[5]; inside the method will leave all the positions undefined!!!